# Strange floating point result behavior despite explicit casting

Tags: php, variables, floating-point, double, decimal

Well I have been on this problem the entire day and I think that qualifies the need for some help.

**PHP**

```
$hour1 = (float) $date1 / 10000;
$hour1 = (float) floor($hour1);

$hour2 = (float) $date2 / 10000;
$hour2 = (float) floor($hour2);

$minute1 = (float) $date1 / 10000;
$minute1 = (float) $minute1 - floor($minute1);
$minute1 = (float) $minute1 / 60;
$minute1 = (float) $minute1 * 100;

$minute2 = (float) $date2 / 10000;
$minute2 = (float) $minute2 - floor($minute2);
$minute2 = (float) $minute2 / 60;
$minute2 = (float) $minute2 * 100;

$date = (float) ($hour1 + minute1) - ($hour2 + minute2);
$date = floatval($date);
```

As you can see I've went a little overboard with the type casting.

**Variable Values**

```
$minute1 = .564478
$hour1 = 19

$minute2 = .9885546
$hour2 = 8
```

`$date = (float) ($hour1 + minute1) - ($hour2 + minute2);`

**IS**

`$date = (float) (19 + .564478) - (8 + .9885546);`

**Now the result given is actually**

`11`

**AND NOT**

`10.575932......`

Curiously, when I do this without variables `echo (19 + .564478) - (8 + .9885546);`... I get the floating point result of `10.575932......`.

I understand that most programming languages round out floating points but I've tried everything including up to explicitly type casting. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = (float) ($hour1 + minute1) - ($hour2 + minute2);
```

Didn't you forget about $ before `minute1` and `minute2` ??

If you had, PHP would treat this vars as constans and count only `$hour1 - $hour2` witch returns 11 in your case

it should look like

```
$date = (float) ($hour1 + $minute1) - ($hour2 + $minute2);
```